# Laravel + VueJS - Component doesn't displayed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

I'm trying to add VueJS in my Laravel app, but my first component is not displayed on my page.

As you can see on the source page, we can see the component "login".
[image]

And this is the associate code:

```
<template>
    <p>Coucou je suis un élément Vue.JS</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "login"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

It's just a simple component that display a string.

Here you have the app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('login', require('./components/Auth/Login.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

But my problem is that nothing appears on the html page :/ It's completely blank...

[image]

If someone could explain what's wrong, it will be so appreciate. Thank in advance.

Comment: npm run dev to recompile your changes! if the console has no errors

Comment: Already done :( Many times, and in the console i have just "You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html". That's it :/

Comment: Is app.js being included? When running vue, you don't actually see the component like that in the source (<login></login>). That usually means vue isn't properly initialized on your app. Do the vue dev tools tell you anything?

Comment: Yes i've added the app.js generated by the compilation in the main template layout before the closing body. And vue dev tool tell me that vue is not detected :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found my mistake. I forget to add theses two lines :

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
```